# How to ignore white spaces from a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to capture "software Issue" for a column in a dataframe. My code is not able to capture forth row which has more than one space in between "SOFTWARE    ISSUE".

```
data['comment'].str.contains("\\bsoftware issue\\b", case = False)

O/P:

Out[53]:

0    False

1     True

2     True

3    False

4     True

Name: comment, dtype: bool


**comment**

software

software issue

found software issue at end

SOFTWARE    ISSUE

   IN SOFTWARE ISSUE ON
```

Kindly suggest on this so that I can able the captures the words which even have spaces in between.

Comment: How this is related to python2.7 and python3.x both?

Comment: Spaces mean, b/w `SOFTWARE` and `ISSUE`, correct?

Comment: @hygull : Yes sir

Comment: @hygull : Do you mean the data for "comment: column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\s+` to detect the space.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"comment": ["software", "software issue", "found software issue at end", "SOFTWARE    ISSUE" ]})
print(data['comment'].str.contains("\\bsoftware\s+issue\\b", case = False))
```

**Output:**

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: comment, dtype: bool
```